# Airflow on_success_callback return cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, slack

I created an slack connection using Slack apps in airflow.

I tested the slack webhook https requests using the code that slack provides and it runs okey. I can see the message in the slack channel.

When I run the callback in Airflow I get:

```
[2020-08-18 16:04:09,068] {taskinstance.py:1030} ERROR - Failed when executing success callback
[2020-08-18 16:04:09,068] {taskinstance.py:1031} ERROR - 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1028, in _run_raw_task
    task.on_success_callback(context)
  File "/utils/airflow_server/webhook_functions/slack_webhook/dag_status_push.py", line 9, in task_fail_slack_alert
    slack_webhook_token = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).password
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py", line 84, in get_connection
    log.info("Using connection to: %s", conn.log_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 320, in log_info
    "XXXXXXXX" if self.password else None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 298, in __get__
    return self.descriptor.__get__(instance, owner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 190, in get_password
    return fernet.decrypt(bytes(self._password, 'utf-8')).decode()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 183, in decrypt
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

My code looks like:

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.slack_webhook_operator import SlackWebhookOperator

SLACK_CONN_ID = 'slack'

def task_fail_slack_alert(context):
    print("I am in task_fail_slack_alert")
    print(str(context))
    slack_webhook_token = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).password
    print("to slack_msg")
    slack_msg = """
            :green_circle: Task Succeed. 
            *Task*: {task}  
            *Dag*: {dag} 
            *Execution Time*: {exec_date}  
            *Log Url*: {log_url} 
            """.format(
            task=context.get('task_instance').task_id,
            dag=context.get('task_instance').dag_id,
            ti=context.get('task_instance'),
            exec_date=context.get('execution_date'),
            log_url=context.get('task_instance').log_url,
        )
    print("to SlackWebhookOperator")
    failed_alert = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_failed_task_push',
        http_conn_id='slack',
        webhook_token=slack_webhook_token,
        message=slack_msg,
        username='airflow')
    print("to execute")
    return failed_alert.execute(context=context)
```

And my connection is something like:
[image]

I don't find any reference to solve this issue anywhere.

Comment: Was `AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY` updated between saving the slack web token and running the task? Also, ensure that the webtoken is the entire webhook endpoint (protocal inclusive)

Comment: @OluwafemiSule what do you mean with protocal inclusive?
AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY updated to what?

Comment: Updated FERNET_KEY and its working

Comment: @mrc Could you please share the solution?

Comment: @mrc What do you mean by update? what did you do to solve it? can you share it step by step?

Comment: @OriWiesel I went to the cfg file and I changed the fernet key and edit the password in my connections. This error is raised becuase Fernet key has been changed between when you stored the connection and running th ejob using that connection